# How do I make a WPF/MVVM application do background processing before displaying a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm fairly new to WPF & MVVM.  I've created a couple standard simple WPF/MVVM applications that show a startup screen and do processing, including displaying other user controls, based on commands within that main window.

But now I want to make a WPF/MVVM monitoring/input-gathering application that starts up without displaying a window, loops through checking the system state until conditions necessitate the window's display, and only THEN displays a window, then processes the user input and goes back to looping.  The user wouldn't be waiting for this window, because it's only shown when there's something that needs the user's attention.  It would run in the background "forever", only showing itself when needed.

I see that I can make my own Main() method, but I still can't figure out the best way to keep it in MVVM, yet only display the window as needed within a larger loop.

Thanks!

EDIT - we finally did the sane thing and made two different processes, one to do the monitoring and one to do the WPFing.  Thanks all!

Comment: You can do processing in the app.xaml.cs file before the window opens but be careful on how long that would take. Users would tend to think something is wrong is they do not see a response to starting an application within 2 seconds. Perhaps consider a info window such as a slash screen while that is taking place.

Comment: Thanks, but it's more of a background process that the user won't usually see - more of popping up to say that attention is needed, when attention usually is NOT needed.  If I did the processing in the app.xaml.cs before showing the window, how would I go back to monitoring for the error condition again after handling the error the first time?

Comment: Use some sort of Notification Window (a.k.a Toast)? It is not available in WPF (as it was in WinForm) but people have created something similar you can use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22876/WPF-Taskbar-Notifier-A-WPF-Taskbar-Notification-Wi

Comment: You could create your own window management system that allowed for passing a parameter that tells it not to load until it has everything it needs, and only then display the view.  That would be a tricky little piece of code to write however.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating a windows service that may/may not display a window.  So I'd recommend Window Service project template, not the WPF Application project template.  Your service can then create the WPF Window when it needs to request information from the user.

Comment: @BrianS Mixing windows service and WPF windows? yuck.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a bad idea to have a windows service show a window.  However, that is what she is describing, and I'm not here to judge.  The better way would be to create a windows tray app, but again, just offering suggestions for the requirements described here.

Comment: @BrianS - upvoted for the very rare (on SO) "I'm not here to judge."  :)  Unfortunately, I've judged and been overruled on the silly thing - it WILL be a WPF app that's also a monitor.  Grrrrrrr.  I'm working my way through forcing it into unnatural acts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Service seems to be the best way to do the monitoring. As soon as user interaction is needed you could signal the rest of the 'world' that something has occured.

A WPF client could pick up the signal and show a UI. The WPF client could be hidden by using a NotifyICon.

MVVM would only be appropriate in the WPF Client. The model contains the status that is monitored, the viewmodel turns this into a model of the view and the view displays the information.

The signal could be a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) that is set by the service and tested by the WPF client. Communication between the service and the client could be implemented by using WCF.